# Append new data to an External Data table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-external-data

If I have a table in Excel, populated via an external data connection, how can I refresh the data in such a way as to insert new rows for new data, but keep the old rows as well?

For example, this is my table:
[image] 

Unfortunately the database that I'm working with **only holds onto the current month's data**, so if I refresh, I'll only get February 2011's data back.  The end result I want is:
[image]  
Are there any built-in Excel options that I'm missing (similar to "External Data Properties"->"Insert entire rows for new data, clear unused cells") or should I go the programmatic route and save the old data in a temp table, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Excel external data is based on a query of the external source, Refresh will update to whatever is in that source.  I think you will need to code a routine to append the external link data to another sheet

Comment: I think you're correct - I was just hoping to avoid doing so.  Thanks!